# bootstrap-vue.js with laravel Unknown custom element: <b-alert> error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Im new to Vuejs and I get the error unknown custom element -

how do i register a custom element - b-alert. I think this element is from bootstrapVue.

```
<template>
<div>
 <b-alert show>Default Alert</b-alert>



  </div> 
   </template>

    <script>
   export default {
    data () {
            return {
                 dismissSecs: 10,
                 dismissCountDown: 0,
                 showDismissibleAlert: false
            }
    },
                  methods: {
             countDownChanged (dismissCountDown) {
                     this.dismissCountDown = dismissCountDown
             },
             showAlert () {
                     this.dismissCountDown = this.dismissSecs
             }

     },

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to register the component as in [Component registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration)

```
import { Alert } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';

components: { BAlert }
```

Since all html tags are turned into dashed by camelcase `BAlert` = `'<b-alert>'`

Alertenativly you can also use

```
components: { 'b-alert': BAlert }
```

Comment: I added components: { 'b-alert': BAlert } to the file, now i get an error BAlert is not defined

Comment: did you use `vue-cli` to setup your project, and did you use `npm install bootstrap-vue`?

Comment: `BAlert` is not defined because you imported `Alert` not `BAlert`.