# Embedding bootstrap-vue <b-form-datepicker>

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to use a <b-form-datepicker> in a vuejs application.

Browser tells me the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <b-form-datepicker> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I am using other bootstrap-vue compoments without problems.
Giving it a 'name' property does not change a thing.

What am I missing here?
The documentation on https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker does not talk about registering any components. (Did I miss a basic fundamental patr when and how to use components?)
I am using the template-script-style pattern for building this part of the gui.
In my `main.js` Í do have a declaration of `import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';`
On other locations using bootstrap-vue elements it works out of the box as far as I have seen.

Somewhat nearest other issue about that for me was https://stackoverflow.com/a/51410592/845117.
But there I am missing the link of the documentation of naming components as well as the import statement with the 'custom' path: `import { Alert } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';`

Did I miss a major part? What is the missing link here for me?

Comment: The datepicker was added in `v2.5.0`. What version of `Bootstrap-Vue` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

@Hiws is absolutely right.

The deal was with the version. I am missing the experience with the npm system.

Thank you!